# What permission am I missing here?

Tags: apt, ffmpeg, download

I am trying to download the ffmpeg package and all of its dependencies into a directory on my computer. 
I use this code to do it

```
sudo apt-get download $(apt-rdepends ffmpeg|grep -v "^ ")
```

It works for the most part until it runs into this:

```
W: Can't drop privileges for downloading as file '/home/daslab/compression/downloaded/ffmpeg2/ffmpeg2theora_0.30-1_amd64.deb' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)
```

What permission am I missing and how do I get it?

Comment: sudo apt install ffmpeg ?

Comment: That would install the package; not just download them.  The most common use-case for `apt download` is to collect the dependencies for either later installation when there is not network available, or for installation on another host which does not have the ability to contact the repo directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re not missing a permission, you’re giving `apt-get` too much privilege; drop the `sudo`:

```
apt-get download $(apt-rdepends ffmpeg|grep -v "^ ")
```

`apt-get download` runs fine as a normal user.

(Technically, you could give the `_apt` user access to the target directory, but it’s simpler and better to drop `sudo`.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it never occurred to me that there was such a thing as too much permission.

Comment: It's not so much _too much_ permission as it is _wrong_ permission.  `_apt` isn't `root`; it may as well be `bob`.  `bob` can't access `alice`'s files, even if `root` can access both `bob` and `alice`'s files.

Comment: @DopeGhoti but the only reason `apt-get` ends up using `_apt` is because it’s run as root when it doesn’t need to be. So the simple solution is to not run it as root, then it won’t try anything with `_apt`.